# Why I get different answers while getting hours from a timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following code

```
Select 
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki')) as hour,
TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki','HH24') as hour2
from dual
```

Output is:

```
HOUR    HOUR2
12       15
```

This function sets time to UTC and then converts to Europe/Helsinki and then gets an hour from the timestamp. Why do I have different answers here?

Comment: It's just my guess, but I think `TO_CHAR` ignores `at time zone ...` part and considers the argument as `UTC` and then implicitly adds time zone offset from your client time zone. I think so because 12 was a correct hour for your GMT+3 timezone, while 15 is an overshoot from 12 by exactly 3 hours.

Comment: `FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')` seems odd. systimestamp has your server time zone included. You're essentially saying that the server zone is wrong and you want to treat whatever time that says it is as if it were UTC - rather than converting it to UTC. Is that really what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 3):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html):

> When extracting from a datetime with a time zone value, the value returned is in UTC.

You are passing in the converted value, which is going to evaluate to something like `2021-06-04 15:14:13 EUROPE/HELSINKI`; when that is implicitly converted back to UTC it becomes `2021-06-04 12:14:13 UTC`, so extract returns 12.

Your conversion seems to be overly complicated, and wrong; it shouldn't be giving you 15 at the time you posted, and the 12 was correct (I think, as you posted at 09:38 UTC) but only because your server happens to be in +03:00 time zone as well (I think, again, from the values you saw).

If you want the current time in Helsinki then you you can simply use `SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki'`.

To pass that into `extract()` without it being treated as UTC, you can cast to a plain timestamp at that point:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki' AS TIMESTAMP)) as hour
```

which gives the correct answer of 13 [at the moment](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/finland/helsinki).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12b480a8ce559a5ab8fd5c620a864e38) (server in UK time zone, so BST)